# yum install not working from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel7, proxysql

I was trying to create a Docker Image for ProxySQL . Following is my `DockerFile`

```
FROM rhel7:latest
USER root

MAINTAINER Ques Zama


# Update the image with the latest packages (recommended)
 RUN yum update -y; yum clean all

# Update image
 RUN yum-config-manager --enable proxysql_repo

# Install ProxySQL
 RUN yum install proxysql -y

# Expose ProxySQL Port 6034
  EXPOSE 6034

# Start the service
  CMD /etc/init.d/service start proxysql
```

I was trying to build the image with below command

```
 sudo docker build --no-cache -t zama_proxysql .
```

But I can it is not able to install the `proxysql` package using `yum` command as mentioned in `Dockerfile` . Following is the message below

```
 Step 6 : RUN yum install proxysql -y
 ---> Running in 54cc1ae88ba3
 Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
 No package proxysql available.
 Error: Nothing to do
 The command '/bin/sh -c yum install proxysql -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I execute the command `yum install proxysql` in commandline , it works fine . But from `Dockerfile` , it  could not find the package. Please note that I have already enabled the repo for `proxysql` in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

Any suggestions to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the repo manually first instead of using yum-config-manager :

```
cat <<EOF | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/proxysql.repo
[proxysql_repo]
name= ProxySQL YUM repository
baseurl=http://repo.proxysql.com/ProxySQL/proxysql-1.4.x/centos/\$releasever
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repo.proxysql.com/ProxySQL/repo_pub_key
EOF
```

This works properly on a FROM centos:7 image.

Comment: Thw repo is already added and is available from commandline ,

Comment: From my understanding, the repository is available for the local command line, not in your docker container.

Comment: @SCO - How do I get the repository to be available in the Dockerfile?  I can run docker build from either Windows or Mac.